# Задать границы окон в Windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi

Есть желание изменить границы открытых окон в Windows 10, а именно - имеется развернутое на весь экран окно. По умолчанию в проводнике системы окно разворачивается максимально по высоте от верхней границы экрана до панели "Пуск" и максимально по ширине от левого до правого края монитора. Если панель "Пуск" переместить на левый, правый, верхний край, то, соответственно, окно подгоняется по размерам под новое расположение панели.

Есть ли возможность как-то искусственно ограничить размеры окна так, чтобы снизу экрана помещалась панель быстрого доступа типа RocketDock и, таким образом, создавалась стилистика систем MacOS, как на [скриншоте](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yZmHyAZ1pWk/maxresdefault.jpg)

Догадываюсь, что это можно реализовать с помощью самописной программы. Тогда нужны подсказки по, если не ошибаюсь, WinApi.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы изменить рабочую область экрана (Working Area), вам нужно создать так называемый AppBar.
Это делается с помощью WinAPI-функции [SHAppBarMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shappbarmessage).

Более подробно написано [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars).
Вот [пример приложения на C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3).

Если само окно AppBar-а вам не нужно, можно его сделать полностью прозрачным (в т.ч. для кликов мышью) с помощью расширенных стилей WS_EX_TRANSPARENT и WS_EX_LAYERED.